# WPF Grid Auto Height and Fixed Height unexpected behaviour when using a RowSpan

Tags: wpf, grid

I have some understanding problems. I have a `Grid` in WPF with alternating fixed row heights and auto row heights.

If I add a `Label` to the rows with auto height in the first column, then this works as I expected.

But if I add a control in column 1 with a `RowSpan`, it was not the rows with the auto height that were resized, but the rows with the fixed height were resized.

Take a look at this example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <Label Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Label1" />

    <Label Grid.Row="3"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Label2" />
    <Label Grid.Row="5"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Label3" />
    <Label Grid.Row="7"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Label4" />

     <Border Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="7"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Height="300"
            Background="Red" />


    <!--<Label Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Hallo" />-->

</Grid>
```

And also not logical if I add a label to the fixed with I can not see this label because the size 5 is to small. Although the row is displayed much bigger.

Comment: Just don't set the `Height` of the Border.

Comment: The behavior you describe is not what I would have predicted either, it does seem that "Auto" was preserved in favour of the fixed height - strange!

Answer (score 2):

I think that is quite interesting behaviour. If you'll look at GridLines sources you'll see constructor:

```
public GridLength(double pixels)
        : this(pixels, GridUnitType.Pixel)
    {
    }
```

It means that by default Height in RowDefenition has second parameter as Pixel.
That is why WPF resizes your grid in your case.

There are several ways to fix it:

1. If you want to cut your control you should add MaxHeight property to Grid's RowDefenitions:

   ```
       <RowDefinition Height="5" MaxHeight="5"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="5" MaxHeight="5"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="5" MaxHeight="5"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="5" MaxHeight="5"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="5" MaxHeight="5"/>
   ```
2. If don't want to cur your control you should add another Row with Height="*":

   ```
       <RowDefinition Height="5" MaxHeight="5"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="5" MaxHeight="5"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="5" MaxHeight="5"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="5" MaxHeight="5"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="5"/>
   ```

And add control to your row:

```
        <Border Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="8"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Height="300"
        Background="Red" />
```

Comment: Ok  the solution with the MaxHeigt works. But this do not  cut the control. The rows with the auto height will be now resized.